# Node / Angular 2: Update navbar and show sidebar after user login

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs5

This is my first project/application using Angular 2. And I am currently stuck in the login problem of the application. So, in my web app:

**Expectations:**

1. I load a login component for the first time. In this case, the navbar shows a "Sign In" button.
2. After correct login, I can go to a dashboard component. In the dashboard component, I can see a sidebar on the left side, and my navbar is updated to show the "Sign Out" button.
3. When I click "Sign Out", it should sign me out gracefully.

For a clearer picture, I've uploaded [an album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpjN0.jpg) showing how the login and dashboard should look like, and the actual happening after login.

**Reality:**

1. I use `localStorage` from Angular 2 to store the current user in key `currentUser` and detect whether user is logged in. As long as it deoesn't value in the `currentUser` key, the login component works fine. Otherwise, it shows an empty dashboard with no title in it.
2. After the login, the sidebar and updated navbar is jumbled up with the login screen, while the dashboard is not showing up.

I've made [a temporary Git repo](https://github.com/baskoroi/back-temp) to show you my code for now.

If you notice, the Angular frontend is connected to a Node.js backend. The Node.js backend works just fine.

I think the main problem points are in my usage of Observables (to tell every subscribing component that user is logged in), the authentication guard on the routes, and maybe the authentication service itself.

To meet the expectations above, I've tried to use Observables and emit the values to the subscribing components. However, the 'reality' points I've mentioned above happened, and I haven't known a way yet to fix it again.

So, can you help show me where the problem is, and what I can do to fix it? I would appreciate your input, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the problem.

The authentication guard was just delivering the `Observable` from `this.authService.isLoggedInObservable()` method. It doesn't deliver the proper value for the routes to know whether the user is actually logged in or not.

If you see in the repo, I use `Observable<boolean>` to tell the other components/routes whether I've logged in or not.

A workaround I did was to actually store a private variable inside the guard. I did this so that the `canActivate()` method inside the guard only returns that private variable: `true` means I'm logged in, `false` otherwise.

How to let that private variable know that I'm now logged in, and its value needs to change?

Within the constructor I made sure that the guard was subscribing for the Observable with that boolean value, and update that variable accordingly.

I just changed the code from `AuthenticationGuard`. Nothing less, nothing more.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router, CanActivate } from "@angular/router";

import { Observable } from "rxjs";

import { AuthenticationService } from "./authentication.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {

    private isLoggedIn: boolean; // to store the "logged in" state

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthenticationService) {

        this.authService.isLoggedInObservable().subscribe((val) => {
            this.isLoggedIn = val; // update as subscribed
            // redirect to login page if not logged in yet
            if (!val) this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
        });
    }

    canActivate() { // only returns that private variable
        return this.isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```